# Arcobjects Multithreading in C++ - 'Aborted' when modifying Geometry

Tags: arcobjects, c++

My project is required to be cross-platform, so I am using the C++ API for ArcObjects. My application creates a new thread which listens to a network socket broadcasting location information. I am attempting to read in the information and add points to my DynamicLayer. 
My problem comes when I try to use a new IPoint in the second thread. I can make the call:

```
IPointPtr newpoint(CLSID_Point);
```

But on the next line when I execute:

```
newpoint->PutCoords(x,y);
```

The application fails with a nonspecific error 'aborted'.

Relavant information: I am creating a new thread by calling `pthread_create` on a static method.

I have read the ESRI document on multithreading (which like the rest of the documentation is woefully absent of c++ specific information), but didn't see anything I thought could be the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try using [IGeometryBridge2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001sn000000)?  It's not geared towards `IPoint` objects, but I suppose you could have a multipoint with just one point in it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This seems like exactly what I need! I'll give it a shot and post again when I have some results.

Comment: That pointer to the IGeometryBridge was probably the right answer for .NET programmers, but it seems that those of us stuck in C++ cannot properly utilize it because many of the method calls require a SAFEARRAY, which is not well supported in ESRI's API

Comment: Hmm, I thought the whole point of `IGeometryBridge2` was to provide support for safe arrays. "The IGeometryBridge interface solves that problem allowing you to pass safe arrays instead."

Comment: That is exactly the problem, I am having great difficulty constructing a SAFEARRAY within ESRI's environment. They provide us with an Array class (which I believe is supposed to encapsulate SAFEARRAY), but I was unable to add IPoint objects to it.

Comment: I think you'd want to use [standard c++ techniques to build a safearray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730840/how-to-create-and-initialize-safearray-of-doubles-in-c-to-pass-to-c-sharp) of [WKSPoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0042000002qw000000) structures.

Comment: I actually ran across that answer when I was trying to create a SAFEARRAY. If I recall, I could not get the SAFEARRAY to pass into the IGeometryBridge2 object if I filled it with WKSPoint structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: **In each thread** you MUST call `::AoInitialize(NULL)` in order to use ArcObjects!